# Disable linking libc in emscripten

Tags: emscripten, asm.js, webassembly

I'm curious if it's possible to have emscripten build a binary without libc.

If I have simple.c:

```
int add1(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

And I don't want to include any of libc, is that possible?

My best attempt so far has been:

```
emcc simple.c -s NO_FILESYSTEM=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=1 -s DEFAULT_LIBRARY_FUNCS_TO_INCLUDE='[]' -s LIBRARY_DEPS_TO_AUTOEXPORT='[]' -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["add1"]' -s USE_SDL=0 -o simple.js -nostdlib
```

But the generated output still includes symbols for malloc, string conversion routines, and so on.

I'm also interested in the same process for generating webassembly; that is, my real goal is generating a webassembly module that contains only a single function. Is this possible with emscripten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emscripten is not currently well-suited for this use case. Object files are bitcode, and anytime linking is used, it wants to include some libraries and JS module code.

For WebAssembly, it is possible to use clang from upstream LLVM trunk along with the `s2wasm` tool from [Binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen). Clang (optionally in conjunction with LLVM's `llc` tool) can generate a `.s` assembly file which `s2wasm` can convert into `wast` (WebAssembly's text format). This file can be converted to wasm binary using Binaryen's `wasm-as` tool or the `wast2wasm` tool from [WABT](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt). This pipeline will turn any undefined references to functions from the C file into wasm imports, which you'll need to manually hook up to JavaScript functions.
There are a few examples of this floating around on the Internet (I found some by googling "webassembly clang s2wasm"). Note also that `s2wasm` does the linker's job of laying out the wasm linear memory, and it has several options that you'll want to be aware of; see its help output and its sources, e.g. the [tool](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/master/src/tools/s2wasm.cpp) and [linker](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/master/src/wasm-linker.h) code.

Comment: This may be a bit complicated, but it works pretty good. I have found a GitHub Gist which was very helpful to me: https://gist.github.com/yurydelendik/4eeff8248aeb14ce763e

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options to build standalone wasm module. Via `emsdk` or via `llvm`. Note, that now emsdk generates code via asm.js backend, and does not support natively some i64 operations like multiplication.

### emsdk

```
emcc your_module.c -v -O3 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o your_module.wasm
```

### native llvm + binaryen

Note, now you need latest llvm from trunk, compiled with wasm support.

```
clang -emit-llvm --target=wasm32 -O3 -c -o your_module.bc your_module.c
llc -asm-verbose=false -o your_module.s your_module.bc
s2wasm --emscripten-glue your_module.s > your_module.wast
wasm-opt -O3 your_module.wast -o your_module.wasm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `-s ONLY_MY_CODE=1` to get a file containing only your compiled code.

See [the possible options](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L583) you can pass to emscripten.

Answer (score 1):

See [WebAssembly Standalone](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly-Standalone), there is also a link to examples in this page.

```
emcc simple.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o simple.wasm
```

To run it in html/js you must provide an `imports` object with `imports.env={memoryBase, tableBase, memory, table}`.  But if you convert wasm file by wabt to wat format you can strip the import section because you don't need neither memory nor table then compile it back to wasm.
Here is an [exemple](https://gist.github.com/kripken/59c67556dc03bb6d57052fedef1e61ab)

Comment: The link might get broken, please consider mentioning the key points/samples in your answer.